# C++ CLI Saxon .NET gives error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'Externally supplied NodeInfo belongs to the wrong Configuration'

Tags: .net, c++-cli, saxon

C++ code :

```
void applyXslt(Saxon::Api::XdmNode^ fxmlFile, Saxon::Api::XsltTransformer^ xsltFile, const std::string& outputFile)
{
    // Apply the xslt to the cached xml
    auto processor = gcnew Saxon::Api::Processor(false);

    xsltFile->InitialContextNode = fxmlFile;
    auto serializer = processor->NewSerializer();    \\ Error occurs here

    System::String^ output = gcnew System::String(outputFile.c_str());
    serializer->SetOutputFile(output);

    xsltFile->Run(serializer);

}
```

It somehow fails to create a serializer , It worked when i created a test project , but now it doesnt seem to work. Is this a bug in Saxon ??

Comment: Are you using two different `Processor` objects? You should normally try to use one single `Procssor` for your code or at least make sure that you don't mix the use of e.g. XsltCompiler/Executable/Xslt30Transformer/XsltTransformer/XdmNode created with one processor with instances created with a different processor.

Comment: You mean I can only have one saxon processor in the whole program ?? I have more then 1 saxon processor but after using it it goes out of scope.

Comment: A simple fix might be to pass the original processor you used to create those `XdmNode` and `XsltTransformer` objects earlier in as well as a parameter and to simply use it to create your Serializer.

Comment: Is there a way to delete a saxon processor (using the delete keyword or the destructor generates a JET RUNTIME ERROR ) because the other saxon processor are like 7 calls back

Comment: See https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/dotnet/dotnetapi.html, you can use different processors as far as I understand it, but you can't mix objects you create from one processor (.e.g. XdmNode, XsltCompiler, Serializer) with ones created from a second one. See the Processor as the central object holding the central configuration, create other Saxon.Api objects from that central processor.

Comment: A JET runtime error with Saxon-HE and c++cli? As with previous questions, if you run into a concrete problem, consider to ask a specific question with minimal but complete details to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is there a way to change the SaxonProcessor of a created object

Comment: As far as I know there is no way, the intended use is to have a central Processor and other Saxon.Api objects are created from it. For more specific questions you might want to ask Saxonica directly in their support forums i.e. https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/boards for Saxon Java and .NET and https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon-c/boards for SaxonC

Comment: Nice , the small fix you gave me worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow you to mark the question as answered, I summarize what seemed to have helped from the comments.

In general, the `Processor` class is central, see https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/dotnet/dotnetapi.html saying

> The first thing the application needs to do is to create a `Processor`.
> The `Processor` holds configuration information for Saxon, and shared
> resources such as the name pool and schema pool. It is possible to run
> multiple processors concurrently if required, but it is usually more
> economical for all Saxon processes within a single application to use
> the same `Processor`.

So based on that your code should hold on to the `Processor` you used to create the `XdmNode` and `XsltTransformer` you already pass in to your function `applyXslt` and pass that processor instance in as well as a parameter to then use it to create that `Serializer`.